# How can I set NODE_OPTIONS from a bash console?

Tags: node.js

I use ubuntu for Windows 10 and after command: "node --v8-options" (in the bash) I decided to permanently change/set options:

```
--max_old_space_size=4096
--optimize_for_size
--gc_interval=100
```

But I dont know how to do that. 
I wrote bash script which changes max_old_space properly

```
export NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=4096
```

But unfortunately with --optimize_for_size and -gc_interval it doesnt work.
I tried:

```
export NODE_OPTIONS=--optimize_for_size
export NODE_OPTIONS=--gc_interval=100
```

but bash says:

```
node: --optimize_for_size= is not allowed in NODE_OPTIONS
node: --gc_interval= is not allowed in NODE_OPTIONS
```

I need help with setting those options. The best way to do that will be  for me a bash script, but I can also write commends manually from keyboard.

Thanks for any kind of help.

Comment: According to https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_node_options_options, `--optimize_for_size` and `--gc_interval` are not in the list of supported options for NODE_OPTIONS env var, unfortunately.